# Equivalent of isinstance for Objects That are Functions

Tags: python

I'm altering some code, that is covered by unit tests. And inside the unit tests something like this happens:

```
def create_object(cls, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['arg1'] = arg1 or DEFAULT1
    kwargs['arg2'] = arg2 or DEFAULT2
    kwargs['arg3'] = arg3 or DEFAULT3
    return cls(kwargs)
```

Basically a bunch of stuff that allows us to use shorthand when writing tests.

I've just done a refactor that means that some of the uninstantiated object classes being passed in require a single non-kwarg argument. The refactor makes sense in the code body, but causes the tests to fail.

Given that I'd rather not rewrite all the failing tests from scratch, the easiest solution would be something like

```
if isinstance(cls, Foo):
    return cls(kwargs, True)
else:
    return cls(kwargs)
```

This fails of course because `cls` isn't actually an instance of anything which is an instance of `Foo`.

At the moment I have a hacky solution that includes adding a flag to the `kwargs`, then checking if it's present, and `pop`ping it from the list if it is.

Is there a better way to check is a function object will return an instance of another class?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check?

Comment: It the class that the function object `cls` represents is an instance of another class. I want something equivalent to `isinstance(cls(), Foo)` but that works like `isinstance(cls, Foo)`.

Comment: What is *returned* by the function `cls`?

Comment: What `class` does a function object represent? What does that mean?

Comment: That depends. It's always a constructor, but it can be a constructor for one of several different classes.

Comment: `cls(kwargs)` isn't actually providing any keyword arguments.

Comment: It is if `kwargs` is a dictionary.

Comment: @Batman: Nope. It's passing a single positional argument. `cls(**kwargs)` would unpack the dict into keyword arguments.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
issubclass(cls, Foo)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How you intuited that this was what was being asked for is beyond me, haha